# How do I override a default view template from another module?

Tags: views, theming, hooks

Drupal provides `hook_theme()`. But is there a hook_theme_alter()? I'm looking for something like [`hook_menu_link_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/6), which overrides hook menu entries, but for the theme. I want to modify a view hook theme entry so I can specify where to look for one of my custom templates. I am not interested in specifying it through the Views interface, since it look for the theme template inside the theme folder, and I want my template in a feature module.

I found [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/6) and [`_theme_process_registry()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/_theme_process_registry/6). You can answer which one is the best to use and why.

Which of these keys should I modify in order to make the view pickup the template from the module?

If I put views-data-export-xml-header--richard-feeds-nokia-movies--views-data-export-1 in the feature, the View defaults to pick up views-data-export-xml-header.tpl.php. If I put that template in the theme layer, the view picks it up (even with the registry alter hook in place).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your feature should implement `hook_theme_registry_alter()`. The use case you describe is exactly what that hook is for. The example code linked on the API page should get you started. The basic idea is to target the entry that corresponds to the entry that `views_theme()` is inserting into the registry, and change the template to match the one in your feature.

Comment: jhedstrom is right: the equivalent of `hook_menu_link_alter()` for `hook_theme()` is `hook_theme_registry_alter()`; `_theme_process_registry()` is a private function that should never be used from third-party modules.

Comment: It sounds logical, but it actually did not work. Refer to http://drupal.org/node/939462#comment-3758480.

Comment: @kiamlaluno UPDATE: Pairing `hook_theme_registry_alter()` with a `_theme_process_registry($registry, 'phptemplate', 'theme_engine', 'mymodulename', $path);` like suggested [here](http://hddigitalworks.com/zh-hans/provide-theme-templates-from-a-module) did the trick. [This issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/939462#comment-3758480) has some interesting information as well. Might want to add that information to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to declare a view template stored in the *template* folder of a custom module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function custom_module_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $extension   = '.tpl.php';
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module');
  $files       = file_scan_directory($module_path . '/templates', '/' . preg_quote($extension) . '$/');

  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $template = drupal_basename($file->filename, $extension);
    $theme    = str_replace('-', '_', $template);
    list($base_theme, $specific) = explode('__', $theme, 2);

    // Don't override base theme.
    if (!empty($specific) && isset($theme_registry[$base_theme])) {
      $theme_info = array(
        'template'   => $template,
        'path'       => drupal_dirname($file->uri),
        'variables'  => $theme_registry[$base_theme]['variables'],
        'base hook'  => $base_theme,
        // Other available value: theme_engine.
        'type'       => 'module',
        'theme path' => $module_path,
      );

      $theme_registry[$theme] = $theme_info;
    }
  }
}
```

You should be easily able to fork it override an existing theme instead of adding a new one.
Hope it helps someone.