# Override Another module's Template file using my Custom Module (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7

**I'm willing to change the `user-profile-item.tpl.php` template provided by the `user` module.**

*I've created a new template file. Now my  question is:*

1. Where do I put the new template `user-profile-item.tpl.php` template
   file? I've created a custom module, should I place it right in the
   custom module's directory?
2. Do I need anything to do so that Drupal
   picks up my template file instead of the default template file?

PS I got this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/hook-theme-alter-how-to-override-a-default-views-template-from-another-module) did not understand. Sorry I'm a newbie :(

**EDIT:**

I solved this using *preprocessors*, I figured out that I can use preprocessors easily without changing template file. I wrote following preprocessor in my module to achieve what I was looking for.

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_user_profile(&$vars){
//    dsm($vars); // prints nice debugging information
    $vars['user_profile']['charity_link'] = array(
    '#markup' => l('Add Charity!', 'my/custom/link' . arg(1)),
    '#weight' => 10
    );
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to write that as answer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/53689/6581 which has the cleanest solution as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had to use the following snippet to get it to work. I think it may be due to the way I set up the original template.

```
<?php
//  unset the original template to set yours.

// Implement hook_theme_registry_alter
function MODULENAME_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['TEMPLATE_TO_OVERRIDE']['template'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME') . '/TEMPLATE_TO_OVERRIDE';
  $theme_registry['TEMPLATE_TO_OVERRIDE']['theme path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME');

}
```

Comment: [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/839376#comment-10180778) is explained with more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to do in a custom theme.

As [noted in the documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7), the registry keys for themes are set up in the following manner:

```
$theme_registry['user_profile'] = array(
  'variables' => array(
    'account' => NULL,
  ),
  'template' => 'modules/user/user-profile',
  'file' => 'modules/user/user.pages.inc',
  'type' => 'module',
  'theme path' => 'modules/user',
  'preprocess functions' => array(
    0 => 'template_preprocess',
    1 => 'template_preprocess_user_profile',
  ),
);
```

So basically, I believe you could simply replace `theme path` key with the path to your module, and your template would be used.

```
<?php
//  unset the original template to set yours.

// Implement hook_theme_registry_alter
function MODULENAME_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['TEMPLATE_TO_OVERRIDE']['theme_path']  =>
    drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME')) 
}
?>
```

Now, you would have to find the proper variable in `$theme_registry`, this code example is not working code. You would  also probably need to copy the original preprocess function in the module since the theme path is now overridden.

There is probably an easier way of doing this, but believe me doing this in a theme is way simpler, and less chances to break existing functionality of existing modules.

In a custom theme scenario, you would just need to have your copy of the custom template in your theme and it would be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for helping, @stefgosselin . Eventually (after Googling a lot) I found another way, I'll post it soon here.

Comment: @giga would you be able to post your other way, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@stefgosselin is absolutely correct but need a little correction in code section.
i am writing the exact code which worked for me.

```
<?php
// Implement hook_theme_registry_alter
function MODULENAME_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['TEMPLATE_TO_OVERRIDE']['theme path']  =
    drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME');
}
?>
```

just try to implement this code inside your custom module and it will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of `mytemplate.tpl.php` located in my module's templates directory overwrites `toolbar.tpl`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_registry_alter().
 */
function lml_node_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module');
  // Override the default template with our own.
  if (isset($theme_registry['toolbar'])) {
    $theme_registry['toolbar']['theme path'] = $module_path;
    $theme_registry['toolbar']['path'] = $module_path . '/templates';
    $theme_registry['toolbar']['template'] = 'mytemplate';
  }
}
```