# Panels template files: Inheriting a tpl file in a sub theme

Tags: theming, panels

In my Drupal custom parent theme, I have included a file called `panels-pane.tpl.php`.
This is the main panel pane template. By including this tpl file in my theme, I can override the one in the Panels module folder, which allows me to control its mark-up.

It all works fine. However, when I enable a sub theme that is based on the parent theme, this particular file is ignored. All the other files are inherited.

How can I get this file to be inherited as well?

Would it be possible to force this to be always loaded regardless of the theme?

Please note: I am talking about overriding the `panels-pane.tpl.php` that comes from the original Panels module. I am *not* talking about creating a [custom Panels layout](https://drupal.org/node/495654).

Steps I have tried:

1. Copying the `panels-pane.tpl.php` into the sub themes template directory.
2. Clearing the caches
3. Uninstalling and then re-enable the parent and sub themes

**UPDATED**
Panels has a file called `panels.module`. In it has a function called `panels_theme()`, which contains the following:

```
  $theme['panels_pane'] = array(
    'variables' => array('output' => array(), 'pane' => array(), 'display' => array()),
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'panels') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'panels-pane',
  );
```

Can I use this to control `panels-pane.tpl.php` from inside a module by using [theme_registry_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25872/override-another-modules-template-file-using-my-custom-module-drupal-7)?

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
function legendary_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
 $theme['panels_pane'] = array(
    'variables' => array('output' => array(), 'pane' => array(), 'display' => array()),
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'legendary') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'panels-pane',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the weird news, just having a `panels-pane.tpl.php` in a parent theme should work. It's working for me in a highly used parent theme. So I'm guessing any theme suggestions or other steps aren't going to cut it...

I would check for typos, in this case I would look at the file name (sounds like that's fine), then I would check the sub-theme info file to make sure that's set correctly (although it sounds like that may also be right)

```
base theme = base_theme_name
```

Then I would check file permissions on tpl/theme folder. 664 tends to work for me, and apache needs access to it and the folder it's in.

If that seems fine my two steps before I panic with drupal are:

```
drush rr
```

restart apache

Hope that helps.