# Overriding exposed filters: Twig has no effect

Tags: 8, theming, views

I want to change the HTML output for exposed filters of given view, on fresh new installation of Drupal 8 (no modules were added to it).

I tried to override views-ui-expose-filter-form.html.twig inside my theme's /templates folder, but it doesn't replace the default implementation. The theme itself works fine; for example, I can override the front page.

The file's description is here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views_ui%21templates%21views-ui-expose-filter-form.html.twig/8.2.x.

What am I doing incorrectly? Should I override another template file, or turn something on in the system for it to work, or the filename is wrong?

Comment: Is this the correct filename you should be using?

Comment: I think so, according to the Drupal documentation on API page (correct me if I'm wrong):  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views_ui%21templates%21views-ui-expose-filter-form.html.twig/8.2.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hook\_theme\_alter(): How to override a default views template from another module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/hook-theme-alter-how-to-override-a-default-views-template-from-another-module)

Comment: @Darvanen How it's a duplicate of post asking on different topic? I don't want to make a hook and I don't want to override default view template, but default expose filter for template (that's huge difference, I know perfectly how to override default view template).

Comment: Just because you don't want to use hooks doesn't mean you don't have to. Views typically doesn't play well with the theme engine, have you *tried* inserting your template into theme suggestions using `hook_theme_alter()`?  Have you even inspected the build to see if there are any theme suggestions in there? I suspect you will find there is no other way.

Comment: @PolGraphic, I think you are looking for `views-exposed-form.html.twig`, this is the output of exposed filters. The other template is from the Views UI, for the form to configure the exposed filter, which you would have to override in the admin theme.