# How can I customize an administrative view template from a custom module?

Tags: views, 9

I created a view with a page display whose path is /admin/content/noun, and whose format is table. I'd like to override the table template with *views-view-table--the-view-name--the-display-id.html.twig*. The view's path means the view is displayed in the admin theme. Where do I put the template?

Creating a Claro's sub-theme doesn't work. Customizing web/core/themes/claro/templates/classy/views/views-view-table.html.twig works, but that's hacking core.

Comment: Sub-theming is the way to go, to avoid hacking core. Tested `drush generate theme`  for the base theme `claro` and it installed just fine. You might only need to clean up the block layout.

Comment: `drush generate theme` with a base theme of claro creates a almost blank file structure from Claro in my themes directory. Enabling "claro_custom" one time is enough to show me that this is not a direction we would want to go in. I updated hook_theme_registry_alter() from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/how-do-i-override-a-default-view-template-from-another-module, but now the table from the view display contains no values, only my customizations which are outside the table. Still trying to get hook_theme() to work.

Comment: After you enabled the theme and set it as default backend theme you may need to adjust the blocks, like re-placing them the same way they were in original Claro. The sub-theme is empty, yes, because all the parent files live in original Claro and you now in your sub-theme add only those again you want to customize. (Overriding the template from a custom module is easier IMHO.)

Comment: I definitely prefer to override the template from a custom module. But what's the base hook for a views template override? I can't tell from views_theme().

Comment: The 'base hook' is 'views_view_table'. Here's the code. ```/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'views_view_table__my_view__my_admin_table' => [
      'base hook' => 'views_view_table',
    ],
  ];
}```